# Подлючение elfinder к codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Скачала elfinder. Делаю все по мануалу https://github.com/Studio-42/elFinder/wiki/Integration-with-CodeIgniter

Контроллер у меня в админке, а папка - в корне,настройки следующие:

```js
'driver' => 'LocalFileSystem', 
 'path'   => '../files/', 
 'URL'    => "http://".$_SERVER['SERVER_NAME']."/files/",
```

Вывожу:

```js
<script type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8">
    $().ready(function() {
        var elf = $('#elfinder').elfinder({
            // lang: 'ru',             // language (OPTIONAL)
            url : '<?=base_url();?>files/elfinder_init'  // connector URL (REQUIRED)
        }).elfinder('instance');            
    });
</script>
```

Файловый менеджер загружается, но выдает ошибку: Unable to connect to backend.
Backend not found.HTTP error 404

В чем моя ошибка?

Answer (score 0):

Разобралась сама. connector URL  должен быть такой

```html
<?php echo base_url(). "index.php/ИмяКонтролераСБольшойБуквы/elfinder_init"?>
```